# Getting data to Heroku psql with heroku app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I've got a Django app up and running on Heroku and have configured it for postgresql. I have ~40000 pieces of data on the local DB. When I push this to Heroku, I don't see any of the data in the Django DB admin atleast. Am I looking in the wrong place or doing something wrong? Here is some settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.postgresql'),
        'NAME': 'csci2133',
        'USER': 'kenny',
        'PASSWORD': '...',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500,

    }
}

#Configure heroku for djangos database
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

I've also tried hosting a file I exported from postgres as a text, SQL file seperated with ;. But this didnt do anything.. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Posting scripts for @DanielRoseman.
File to write CSV to Django objects
EDIT2: Changed to show the solution!

```
# Full path and name to your csv file
csv_filepathname="./coord.csv"
# Full path to the directory immediately above your django project directory
your_djangoproject_home="../"
############ All you need to modify is above ############

import sys,os
import string
sys.path.append(your_djangoproject_home)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ='visualize.settings'
import django
django.setup() ###NEED THIS AND THE ABOVE LINE TO RUN! THIS SOLVED IT

from visualize.models import tweets

import csv
dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

i=0
for row in dataReader:
    i=i+1
    tweet = tweets()
    tweet.id = i
    tweet.tag = row[0].translate(None, string.punctuation)
    xcoord = row[1]
    ycoord = row[2]
    datetime = row[3]
    tweet.save()
```

Comment: You will have to transfer the Postgresql data as well. There are many strategies to do that.

Comment: This and your previous question show some confusion, but I'm not sure what you are confused about. There's no point showing your settings, because your local db I is overwritten with the postgres config from the environment. These are two completely separate databases; you need to load data into your app running on Heroku just as you did on the vein running locally.

Comment: @KlausD.That is what I've been attempting to do, but I can't seem to get anything to work

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is what I'm having trouble with. I've tried multiple things such as entering data manually on the psql terminal then migrating, which showed nothing on my app, I've tried hosting an exported psql file (as I mentioned) which did not get loaded into my DB properly. The only way I can have any sort of data is if I manually enter it in the admin page on the heroku app, which I cannot possibly do for 40,000 entries. I've also tried using the heroku backup method, but no luck.

Comment: How did you get the data into your existing sqlite database?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I wrote a script to import a CSV into Django. It essentially converts each CSV value into a 'tweet' Django object and saves it. My local psql picks this up as well.
EDIT: If you meant the hosted heroku app, I manually entered that. Only about 3 entries at the moment just to test.

Comment: So can you not run that script via `heroku run`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, it gives me a 'Apps aren't loaded yet' error. (Raised appregistrynotready error)

Comment: So we should look at fixing that problem, then. Can you post the code of this script?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done!

Comment: You need to [call `django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I put the command right below os.enviro line, and it didn't change anything

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry I had 2 copies of the scripts. That worked. Thank you!